# Oracle Advance Queue - Dequeue Condition is not working

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, queue, oracle12c

I am trying to dequeue message with a specific priority using deq_condition (in Oracle Advance Queue), but always getting no message found. I have tried the following:

```
  dequeue_options.deq_condition := 'tab.priority = 10'; 
  dequeue_options.deq_condition := 'priority = 10';
```

I have also tried to return a true condition like this:

```
  dequeue_options.deq_condition := '1 = 1';
```

but always getting no message found and if I remove this condition then I get the queued message. any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple check if in the queue is a message with the given priority. Substitute `aqtab` for your queue table name

```
 select * from aqtab where priority = 10 order by ENQ_TIME;
```

Very probably you'll see no messege, as this condition `priority = 10` is simple added to the query performing the dequeue.

Note, that to set the message priority you use message properties

```
 l_message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
```

Simple assign the required priority ...

```
 l_message_properties.priority := 10;
```

... and pass the properties as a parameter to the `DBMS_AQ.enqueue`

After a `commit` you should see the message in the queue table using the above query and you should be able to *dequeue* it with the `deq_condition`

Comment: Hi Marmite, thanks for the replay. I found out that I had wrong message order and that is why I was not getting any message

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are correct
`dequeue_options.deq_condition := 'priority = 10';`
`dequeue_options.deq_condition := 'tab.priority = 10';`

But if you are using deq condition you should take care about `navigation` parameter.
The easiest option is repeat dequeue operation after exception appears. (queue snapshot will be reseted).

or add `dequeue_options.navigation := DBMS_AQ.FIRST_MESSAGE;`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. I already have the navigation set to first message 
      dequeue_options.wait            := 1;
      dequeue_options.consumer_name   := 'IS_BROADCAST';
      dequeue_options.dequeue_mode    := DBMS_AQ.locked;
      dequeue_options.navigation := DBMS_AQ.FIRST_MESSAGE;
      dequeue_options.deq_condition := 'tab.priority = 10'; 

but still not working

Comment: Edit question and add more details